# What is autoremove trying to do?

Tags: apt, kernel

```
Seuraavat paketit POISTETAAN:
libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libmecab2 linux-headers-5.4.0-52
linux-headers-5.4.0-52-generic linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic
mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
```

Why does autoremove want to remove these packages? I'm pretty sure I shouldn't accept.

I have Ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT: uname -r produces:
5.4.0-54-generic

Wait a minute, I just got a kernel update. I'm stupid.

Comment: Add to your question the complete output of `uname -r` (the kernel that you are running). Kernels update frequently, and autoremoval of older kernels is quite normal.

Comment: These are old kernel packages. Per default, Ubuntu saves 2 kernel versions, so you can boot into your "current" kernel after upgrading, and older kernel packages are removed.

Comment: I got it, deleted the outdated kernel. Only the newest for me.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you want to install package `A`, apt is going to install package `B` and `C` because package `A` won't work without them, but since you never asked for package `B` and `C` and no other package needs them, if you remove package `A` apt will realize you don't need package `B` and `C` anymore.

There are other scenarios as well; for example, if you update a package, it may not depend on some packages it was before.

If apt recognize any of these packages which you don't need, it will tell you that you can remove them with `apt autoremove`.

**Is it safe?** Not entirely, you may have installed other packages without apt, and they may need these packages to work, and apt won't recognize them; this is why apt don't remove them by default and asking you to remove them, if you know you don't need them anywhere else.

Comment: I'm prrrretty sure that I shouldn't delete kernel related packages, but not why apt wants me to do so.

Comment: @meaj-gnu-linux Just because these packages are related to kernel doesn't mean you need them, I'm auto removing these packages every few weeks without a problem because they became useless. I added some extra information to my answer, please read.